# Please Check my solution and correct me (Testing of hyposthesis)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

A sample of size 1 is taken from Poisson($\lambda$).To test $H_0:\lambda=1$ against $H_1:\lambda=2$,Consider a nonrandomised test $\phi(x)=1$ if $x>3$ and $0 \text{ for } x\leqslant3$.Find type I error and power of the test.
If it is required to have aize equals 0.05,how should one modify the test.
I have calculated the type 1 error and power which are 0.019 and 0.857 respectively.
For the second part I am considering $\phi(x)=\gamma(x) \text{ when }x=3$
And then I have
$P_{\lambda=1}(x>3)+\gamma(x)P(x=3)=0.05$ but from this I am getting $\gamma(x)$ negetive but it must lie between 0 and 1. PLEASE CHECK AND JUST TELL ME WHERE I AM WRONG.

Comment: The formulae following "And then I have" make no sense: please check for typographical errors.  That might be enough to resolve your question.

Comment: I wrote it based on the size 0.05 condition.For randomised test $E(\phi(x))=0.05$.Is it wrong?

Comment: It doesn't make enough sense to decide whether it's right or wrong.  Think about what you mean by "$\gamma(x)$" and why you are subscripting one of the P's with "$\lambda=1$" and not subscripting the other.  I would *guess* that you intend all of them to mean probabilities under the null hypothesis so that $P(x\gt 3) = 0.019$ and $P(x=3)=0.080,$ but in that case it's obvious $\gamma(x)$ must be close to $1/2$ and certainly is not negative.

Answer (score 0):

I will use notation that I hope is clear, and R statistical software
to do probability computations, which you should check using a method
appropriate for your class--computation using PDF, printed table, or software. [In R, a Poisson CDF is denoted `ppois`.]

You are testing $H_0: \lambda = 1$ against the simple alternative
$H_1: \lambda = 2.$ Take one observation $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda).$
Accept if $X \le 3$ and Reject if $X > 3.$

For reference, here is a plot of the two Poisson distributions involved (blue for $H_0$
and red for $H_1).$ The  vertical dotted line separates the acceptance and rejection regions.

From a practical point of view, finding a useful test will be
difficult. The null and alternative distributions are somewhat
similar, and it will be difficult to distinguish between them
with only a single observation.

[image]

(a) $P(\text{Type I Error})$ $ = P(X > 3\,|\,\lambda = 1)$ $=
1 - P(X \le 3\,|\,\lambda = 1)$  $\approx 0.0190.$

```
1 - ppois(3, 1)
[1] 0.01898816
```

(b) The power is $P({Rej}\,|\,\lambda=2)$ $= P(X > 3\,|\,\lambda = 2)$
$ = 1 - P(X \le 3\,|\,\lambda = 2)$ $\approx 0.1429.$ [From a
practical point of view, this would be a disappointingly low power.]

```
1 - ppois(3, 2)
[1] 0.1428765
```

It seems you may have computed $P(\text{Type II Error})$ $ = P(X \le 3\,|\,\lambda = 1)$ $\approx 0.8571.$  Power is $1 - P(\text{Type II Error}).$

```
ppois(3,2)
[1] 0.8571235
```

(c)  Unless you use a randomized test, you cannot test at exactly
the 0.05 significance level.

If you reject for $X > 3,$ then the size of the test is 0.019, as
shown above. If you want a slightly larger probability of Type I Error,
you need  to increase this probability. You could reject tor $X > 2,$
but then you will have a test of size $0.0803:$

$P(\text{Type I Error})$ $ = P(X > 2\,|\,\lambda = 1)$ $=
1 - P(X \le 2\,|\,\lambda = 1)$  $\approx 0.0803.$

```
1 - ppois(2, 1)
[1] 0.0803014
```

So to get a test of size exactly $0.05$ you will have to randomize
between rejecting for $X > 3$ and rejecting for $X > 2.$

I don't understand the (undefined) notation you are using for this,
but you should be able to figure out the probabilities for these
two rejection rules that would give exactly the required size.
Essentially, you need to find $p$ such that $0.0190p + 0.0190(1-p) = 0.0500.$